# php soapclient to xml request

Tags: php, xml, xsd, request, soap-client

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "http://www.xxx.com/demo/webservice/wsHotel.sh",'uri' => "http://www.xxx.com/demo/", 'encoding' =>"ISO-8859-9"));

$parm['login'] = "UserName";
$parm['pass'] = "Pass";
$parm['agency_code'] = "AgencyCode";
$parm['letters'] = "Germany";
$inf = ($client->__soapCall("destinationListByLetterV2",array($parm)));`
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <ns1:destinationListByLetterV2 xmlns:ns1="urn:http://www.xxx.com/demo/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <params xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Array" ns2:arrayType="xsd:string[4]">
  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">UserName</item>
  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Pass</item>
  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">AgencyCode</item>
  <item xsi:type="xsd:string">Germany</item>
  </params>
  </ns1:destinationListByLetterV2>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

missing parameter problem? How to soapclient request to xml request?

Comment: Hi, can you be a little more specific with your question?  [SoapClient](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) will create an XML payload as that is the nature of SOAP.  The request is sent to the endpoint specified when you instantiate SoapClient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$parm['login'] = "UserName";
$parm['pass'] = "Pass";
$parm['agency_code'] = "AgencyCode";
$parm['letters'] = "Germany";
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
$result = $client->destinationListByLetterV2($parm);
```